# How to use unicode characters in Products url in magneto2

Tags: magento2, product-urls

I need to use the arabic letters in the magento2 product url.. I had researched more.. still i had no answer. I am using magento 2.2.6 version

Anyone know please help me to this requirement. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i had found one custom module on this  [link](https://github.com/studioraz/magento2-unicode-url) It works great. We can able to Use the unicode urls for products / Categories and CMS pages. :)